# How to skip files which are in use with the SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure

Tags: visual-c++

I have a small problem with the SHFILEOPSTRUCT structure. I try to delete files in a temp directory. If there are some files in use the structure doesn't delete any file.

But I will delete all files, which are not in use without any display of a dialog.

How could I fix this?

As flag I use at the moment FOF_NOCONFIRMATION.

**Edit**

Oh I'm wrong. I use FOF_NOCONFIRMATION and FOF_NO_UI as flag and nothing happens. The structure returns 32.

If I just use FOF_ NOCONFIRMATION, a dialog box pop up and I could skip all files which are in use. All other files will be deleted.

If SHFILEOPSTRUCT can’t skip, how could I handle that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it has that capability -- at least as far as I can tell, you're pretty much stuck re-implementing the same general capability if you want to continue without user intervention in spite of any problems that might arise.